# In Google Analytics traffic channels, what's the difference between "direct" and "(direct)"?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

What is the difference between `direct` and `(direct)`?

Under *Acquisition-> All Traffic-> Channels-> Other*, the first two sources are `(direct)` followed by `direct`. Both have the same medium: `direct`. However the differ greatly in the number of users they get.